# Removing views from navigation controller that are not being shown

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller that controls a stack of views. The app is an alphabet card app that you scroll through so there are a lot of pages. To reduce the memory usage I want to remove the views from the stack that are not being shown. I want to remove the view you push from so the stack underneath is empty. I cannot make it work so need some help. I have the code to segue below. Would this work to reduce the memory?

```
func showCViewController() {
    let view4 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CView") as! CViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view4, animated: true)

    //My code that doesn't work
    let view5 = self.storyboard?.insViewControllerWithIdentifier("BView")
    self.view5.removeFromSuperview!()       
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  Does it compile?  Does it crash?  Does it launch missiles?  Moreover, are you absolutely certain that memory is actually an issue here or are you optimizing prematurely?

Comment: I have tested with 1-4 views and it bloats by 10mb of memory per view. It doesnt crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A navigation controller is designed as a stack. You can only add or remove view controllers to/from the top of the stack. It isn't possible to remove view controllers out from under the top view controller.

You need a different style of parent view controller to do what you want. I suggest looking at the UIPageViewController. It does either an iBooks style page curl transition or a slide-sideways transition like the pictures app in iOS.

It also isn't that hard to create your own parent view controller that has custom behavior. Support for that was added in iOS 6 and has been extended since then.

Comment: I did make one with the UIPageViewController but it instantiated all the views at launch. I have found one that purges the views that are not in use. I have to work on that one. Thanks for your help.